# TypeScript Error: No overload matches this call' in Middleware Function written for NextAuth

Tags: next.js, getserversideprops

I'm encountering a TypeScript error while working with NextAuth middleware in my Next.js application. The error message I'm receiving is:
`No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 4, '(args_0: GetServerSidePropsContext): Promise<Session | null>', gave the following error. Argument of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => Response | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetServerSidePropsContext'. Overload 2 of 4, '(args_0: (req: NextAuthRequest) => void | Response | Promise<void | Response>): AppRouteHandlerFn', gave the following error. Argument of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => Response | null' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: NextAuthRequest) => void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'. Type 'Response | null' is not assignable to type 'void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void | Response | Promise<void | Response>'.`

I have a middleware function that is supposed to handle authentication logic using NextAuth, but it seems that the function signature is not matching what NextAuth expects.

Here's my middleware function:

```
//middleware.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

import authConfig from "@/auth.config";
import {
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  apiAuthPrefix,
  authRoutes,
  publicRoutes,
} from "@/routes";

const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;

  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isAuthRoute) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl))
    }
    return null;
  }

  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", nextUrl));
  }
  return null;
})

// Optionally, don't invoke Middleware on some paths
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
}
```

I'm unsure how to correctly adjust my middleware function to match the expected parameter types of getServerSideProps. Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply replace all `return null;` with `return;`